# Problem reading AVRO messages from a Kafka Topic using Structured Spark Streaming (Spark Version 2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187/ Scala version 2.11.8)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

**I am invoking spark-shell like this**

spark-shell --jars kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera1.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar,spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar,avro-1.9.1.jar

**After That I read from a Kafka Topic using readStream()**

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 
"kafka-1.x:9093,kafka-2.x:9093,kafka-0.x:9093").option("kafka.security.protocol","
SASL_SSL").option("kafka.ssl.protocol","TLSv1.2").option("kafka.sasl.mechanism","PLAIN").option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config","org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule 
required username=\"token\" password=\"XXXXXXXXXX\";").option("subscribe", "test-topic").option("startingOffsets", 
"latest").load()

**Then I read the AVRO Schema File**

val jsonFormatSchema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/root/avro_schema.json")))

**Then I make the DataFrame which matches the AVRO schema**

val DataLineageDF = df.select(from_avro(col("value"),jsonFormatSchema).as("DataLineage")).select("DataLineage.*")

**This Throws an Error on me :**

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType;

**I could fix this Problem by replacing the jar spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar with spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0-palantir.31.jar**

**Issue:**

DataLineageDF.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("append").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).start

Fails, with this Error

Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = ad836d19-0f29-499a-adea-57c6d9c630b2, runId = 489b1123-a2b2-48ea-9d24-e6744e0959b0]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.boxedType(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;)Ljava/lang/String;

which seems to be related to In-compatible jars. If anyone has any idea what's going wrong please comment

Comment: try to using same version of spark in all libraries.

Comment: I am using this 2.4.0-palantir.31.jar because there isn't one for 2.3.1 or 2.3.0.